# Matplotlib animation running at double speed expected

Tags: python, matplotlib

I coded a simple animation example and ran it at 30 fps, but it seemed to be running much faster than I expected. I timed it, and sure enough, it is running at double speed. It appears there are somehow two instances of a timer running that are slightly offset. Here is a short example that reproduces the behaviour. However, the error only occurs 70% of the time or so. Is there something I'm doing wrong in how I am using the animation package, or should I delve deeper into the matplotlib code and try to submit an issue on GitHub?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import time

class TestAnimation(object):
    def __init__(self, fps=30):
        # Set up animation
        self.render_dt = 1.0/fps
        self.t = time.time()
        self.fig = plt.figure(3)
        self.line, =  plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1])

        # Run animation
        frames = np.arange(100)
        print "interval = %f ms" % (self.render_dt * 1000)
        self.started = False
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update, frames,
                                           interval=self.render_dt * 1000, blit=True)
        # raw_input("Push enter to begin animation")
        self.started = True

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

    def update(self, idx):
        # if idx > 0 and not self.started:
        #    raise Exception("Animation has not yet been started!")
        dt = time.time() - self.t
        self.t = time.time()
        print "dt = %.3f, idx = %d, t = %f" % (dt, idx, time.time())
        self.line.set_data([0, 1, 2], [0, 2, float(idx)/50])
        return [self.line]

anim = TestAnimation()
anim.show()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. 1/30fps = 0.033 seconds. Instead running this code I see 0.047 seconds. Meaning the animation run *slower*  than expected.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the issue does not happen every time I run the code, even on my machine. As a result, I'm not confident that it all machines will be able to reproduce the issue. On my machine the problem occurs at fast speeds (like 10 or 30 fps) but not at slow speeds (like 1 fps). I think there's a race condition or something somewhere.

Comment: The more information you can give about the environment you run this in ("my machine") the higher the chances, someone can help here.

Comment: I'm running Python version 2.7.6 and Matplotlib version 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.5.  My processor is a 3 GHz Intel Xeon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on. Turns out the problem only occurs when the TkAgg backend is being used and that the problem is caused by a TkTimer being restarted during a callback.

Tk uses single shot callbacks, which mean that Matplotlib's TkTimer class has to create a new Tk callback every time the timer goes off using the [Tk.after()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) function. When the TkTimer is stopped it cancels the Tk callback using the [Tk.after_cancel()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after_cancel-method) function. However, the new Tk callback isn't created until the end of TkTimer callback, which means trying to stop the TkTimer within a TkTimer callback will fail. Starting the timer then causes a second Tk callback to be created, thus resulting in the animation appearing to run at double the speed. Here is a short snippet of code that reproduces the issue:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


class TestAnimation(object):
    def __init__(self, fps=10):
        # Set up animation
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.axes = plt.subplot(111)
        self.fig.show()
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        self.render_dt = 1.0 / fps
        self.t = time.time()
        self.count = 0
        self.line, = plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], animated=True)

        # Save background
        self.background = self.fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axes.bbox)

        # Run animation
        self.event_source = self.fig.canvas.new_timer()
        self.event_source.interval = self.render_dt * 1000
        print("Create new TkTimer with interval %f ms" % self.event_source.interval)
        self.event_source.add_callback(self.update)
        self.event_source.start()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

    def update(self):
        dt = time.time() - self.t
        self.t = time.time()
        idx = self.count % 100
        if idx == 10:
            print("TkTimer Start, Stop")
            self.event_source.stop()
            self.event_source.start()
        print "dt = %.3f, idx = %d, t = %f" % (dt, idx, time.time())

        self.fig.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.line.set_data([0, 1, 2], [0, 2, float(idx) / 50])
        self.axes.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.fig.canvas.blit(self.axes.bbox)
        self.count += 1
```

The output below shows the timer running at the expected speed of 10 Hz until the timer is restarted during a callback. When the timer is restarted, two callbacks fire every 10th of a second instead of only 1.

```
Create new TkTimer with interval 100.000000 ms
dt = 0.177, idx = 0, t = 1534262220.665633
dt = 0.103, idx = 1, t = 1534262220.769119
dt = 0.104, idx = 2, t = 1534262220.873422
dt = 0.105, idx = 3, t = 1534262220.978350
dt = 0.105, idx = 4, t = 1534262221.083121
dt = 0.112, idx = 5, t = 1534262221.195082
dt = 0.105, idx = 6, t = 1534262221.299866
dt = 0.105, idx = 7, t = 1534262221.404975
dt = 0.105, idx = 8, t = 1534262221.509763
dt = 0.105, idx = 9, t = 1534262221.614287
TkTimer Start, Stop
dt = 0.104, idx = 10, t = 1534262221.718872
dt = 0.100, idx = 11, t = 1534262221.819030
dt = 0.005, idx = 12, t = 1534262221.823720
dt = 0.100, idx = 13, t = 1534262221.923745
dt = 0.005, idx = 14, t = 1534262221.928303
dt = 0.100, idx = 15, t = 1534262222.028263
dt = 0.005, idx = 16, t = 1534262222.032788
dt = 0.100, idx = 17, t = 1534262222.132509
dt = 0.004, idx = 18, t = 1534262222.136965
dt = 0.100, idx = 19, t = 1534262222.236865
dt = 0.005, idx = 20, t = 1534262222.241497
dt = 0.100, idx = 21, t = 1534262222.341490
dt = 0.005, idx = 22, t = 1534262222.346316
dt = 0.100, idx = 23, t = 1534262222.446195
dt = 0.005, idx = 24, t = 1534262222.450940
```

Looking at the animation class shows why the TkTimer is being restarted inside of a callback. On the first TkTimer callback in the animation class, it draws a couple things which gives control to Tk. As a result of the drawing, Tk triggers a resize_event and a draw_event. The animation class pauses the TkTimer while the resize is occurring and restarts it when it is finished. For whatever reason, sometimes these callbacks happen inside of the TkTimer callback, causing these problems to occur.