# Funcanimation embedded in Tkinter not properly stopping while blitting, Animation display rate increase after window resize

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, animation

**Problem:**
I am having issues with an embedded funcanimation plot in a tkinter GUI.  I am having trouble breaking into the funcanimation object to tell it to stop.  the consequence of not properly stopping the animation is that I end up with timer after calls happening after my app is closed. An added wrinkle is that when I expand the tkinter window to full screen the animation speeds up significantly but when closing this speed leads to more leftover after calls.

**Current Solution:**
After lots of research on this problem my current solution is to set `repeat=False` in the funcanimation initiation and then have a function that produces data check a boolean and if `False` return nothing.  This strategy starves the funcanimation of frames and allows it to stop and be killed with the `self.ani.event_source.stop()` call.

**Wrinkle:**
This solution works great for me while the animation is running slower.  here is where the wrinkle comes in; when the window is resized using the windows maximize button in the top right on the window the animation *speeds up!*. Frame rate goes from 12fps to 25fps. This only happens when resized with the windows button in the top right, if I drag the frame it does not happen leading me to think this is a Windows thing.  This increased frame rate persists even after I minimize the window again.  Because `blit=True` the `init_func` is called on the resize and I can figure out why or how this would speed things up. is there a event flush that happens? What is the resize doing?

**Goal:**
Get the maximum display rate out of my funcanimation from the start (like the speed after I maximize the window) but make sure that all the aftercalls are properly canceled so they are not scheduled after the gui has been closed.  see code below. thank you for  the help.

**Plotting Class:**

```
class ShowImage(MplMap,Thread):

def __init__(self, master):
    #super().__init__
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.setDaemon(True)
    self.master = master
    #self.to_live_queue = to_live_queue
    self.mplmap = MplMap
    if self.image is None:
        self.image = self.grabFrame() #grabFrame is inherited from MplMap and returns a list of 2 arrays
    v = np.linspace(0, 16383, num=5, endpoint=True)
    self.ax2 = self.fig2.add_axes([0.075,0.075,0.85,0.85])
    self.ax2.set_anchor('N')
    self.ax2.spines['left'].set_color(self.THEME_COLOR)
    self.ax2.spines['right'].set_color(self.THEME_COLOR)
    self.ax2.spines['top'].set_color(self.THEME_COLOR)
    self.ax2.spines['bottom'].set_color(self.THEME_COLOR)
    self.ax2.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False,
            labelleft=False, labelbottom=False)
    self.ax2.set_title('Live Image')
    self.ax2.title.set_color(self.THEME_COLOR)
    self.im = self.ax2.imshow(self.image[0], cmap=self.COLORMAP,vmin=0,vmax=16383)
    divider = make_axes_locatable(self.ax2)
    self.cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="3%", pad=0.05)
    self.cbar = self.fig2.colorbar(self.im,cax=self.cax, orientation='vertical',ticks=v)
    self.cbar.outline.set_edgecolor(self.THEME_COLOR)
    self.cax.tick_params(axis='y',colors=self.THEME_COLOR)
    self.cax.set_yticklabels(['{:.0%}'.format(i/16383) for i in v])
    self.cax.yaxis.label.set_color(self.THEME_COLOR)
    #self.fig2.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.07)
    self.canvas2.draw()
    self.root.update()
    self.running=False
    
def clear_image(self):
    self.im.set_data(np.zeros((128,128)))
    self.root.update_idletasks()
    print('init_func')
    return [self.im]
def run(self):
    self.running=True
    self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig2, self.show_image, self.data_gen,blit=True,repeat=False,init_func=self.clear_image, interval=50,cache_frame_data=True)
    return
def data_gen(self):
    while self.running:
        yield self.grabFrame() #grabFrame is inherited from MplMap and returns a list of 2 arrays
    return
def show_image(self,args):
    self.im.set_data(args[0])
    self.root.update_idletasks()
    return [self.im]

def cancel_self(self):
    self.running = False
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.ani.event_source.stop()
    self.ani._stop()
    self._clear2()
    print('canceled')
    return
```

**Launching Function:**
this is a threaded class that is why i need the `.start()` which calls the `run` function above.

```
self.SImg = ShowImage(self.root)
self.SImg.start()
```

**Killing Function:**

```
self.SImg.cancel_self()
self.SImg.join()
```

these two calls are linked to the window close button at the top right of the frame with `root.wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',test_gui._quit)` which basically goes out an stops and joins all the other running threads in my program.

**Example error:**
This is the error I get upon launching my program after it has been closed while displaying at the higher frame rate after being maximized.

```
    invalid command name "2102617692744_on_timer"
    while executing
"2102617692744_on_timer"
    ("after" script)
```

Comment: found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426647/matplotlib-animation-running-at-double-speed-expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem here:
[Matplotlib animation running at double speed expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426647/matplotlib-animation-running-at-double-speed-expected)

the resize event stops and restarts the `event_source` which for some reason sets the animation up to run at the right rate.  I simply added the following lines in the `show_image()` function and an integer variable in the `init`.

```
 if self.i==0:
        self.ani.event_source.stop()
        self.ani.event_source.start()
        self.i+=1
```

still unsure why I have to explicitly do this when starting my animation to get it to run at the proper speed but it works.